# Working around memory issues caused by global static variables

Tags: c++, memory-management, static, global-variables, valgrind

Caveat: This question arose because I have to work with a huge pile of awful code, without proper documentation, written by someone else as a research project 6 years ago. Obviously a better solution is *not* to cause these issues in the first place, with proper design...

That said the question is: What is the best way to get out of a situation like this:

1. A class allocates memory on the heap, and frees it in the destructor.
2. Somewhere, an instance of the class is declared at global scope.
3. A function exists that initializes this instance.
4. That function's return value is used to initialize a static variable.
5. The globally scoped variable is used outside of the static scoping.

Minimal working example:

File "myclass.h":

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class myclass{
        vector<int> *onTheHeap;
public:
        myclass(int len=0){
                onTheHeap = new vector<int>(len);
        }

        ~myclass(){
                delete onTheHeap;
        }

};

#endif
```

file "static_loader.cpp"

```
#include "class.h"
myclass existsForever;

int cause_static_global_creation(){
        existsForever = myclass(5);

}

static int bootstrap = cause_static_global_creation();
```

and file "main.cpp":

```
#include "class.h"

extern myclass existsForever;

int main(){
        return 0;
}
```

Build with:

```
g++ -g -c static_loader.cpp
g++ -g main.cpp static_loader.o
```

and run as:

```
 valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

Result: The variable is freed when its destructor is called in the exit handler's below main, but *also* in the static_initialization_and_destruction_0 function below main from static_loader!

Is there a way to ensure that these variables are freed *exactly* once that doesn't involve re factoring the code extensively? In the library I have to work with, there are several dozen instances of this pattern...

EDIT:

Adding functions:

```
    void operator=(myclass other){
            delete this->onTheHeap;
            this->onTheHeap = other.onTheHeap;
    }
```

and

```
    myclass(const myclass& other){
            this->onTheHeap = new vector<int>(*(other.onTheHeap));
    }
```

Does not change the behavior.

Second EDIT:

```
    myclass& operator=(const myclass& other){
            delete this->onTheHeap;
            this->onTheHeap = new vector<int>(*(other.onTheHeap));
            return *this;
    }
```

Resolves all the issues. My library has a memory leak with sources like this anyway, but I'm no longer sure how to reproduce it. At least it's not this though, and thanks for the suggestions on refactoring etc. as well!

Comment: Are you looking for an add-on design pattern, testing framework / way to verify this works correctly, etc.?  Any of the above?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific: I want to eliminate the double free, preferably by modifying only class.h (which is easy for me to do), and without modifying the other two files (which is much harder).

Comment: Honestly in my experience I'd be open to refactoring.  Consider the following:
1)  Is this a long-running application or does it have a chance of becoming long-running in the future?  If no then memory leaks may be acceptable and not worth the effort of fixing.
2)  Will you be working on the code a lot?  If so then refactoring into good design may have ROI that pays for itself relatively quickly.  This is the solution more often than people wish were true, but turns out developing and maintaining quality code is intrinsically expensive.

Comment: @djechlin a good point. Maybe I'll just have to bite the bullet and refactor it.

Comment: Why manage a pointer to a `vector<int>` when you can just make the `vector<int>` a member?  It stores it's internals on the heap anyway.

Comment: Okay, actually please note you have this situation - global static variables are never destroyed so whatever memory they have isn't supposed to be freed until program exits.  So for THOSE your options really are refactor or leak until program end, and again, if you're not running out of memory leak may be acceptable.

Comment: Also, never include "using namespace std" in a header file, it pollutes the namespace of everything that includes the header no matter how indirectly.

Comment: Is there really not an assignment operator for this class? That's the only way offhand I can think that this might actually cause the double free of the memory.

Comment: The double free is probably caused by the fact that there isn't a decent copy constructor and it's being default copy constructed somewhere with a copy of the pointer.  Hence when the destructor get's called it's going to delete a copy of the pointer constructed by another instance.

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a private copy and assignment operator and see if your code still compiles, if it doesn't then you've probably found your problem.

Comment: @Benj The provided code is a minimal working example, but sorry for the lack coding standards nonetheless. With a proper copy constructor, I still get the double free. Updating the working example to reflect this. The minimal working example uses a heap allocated vector to demonstrate the concept. The real situation uses heap allocated objects that actually ought to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is broken. `myclass existsForever;` is initialized not by `cause_static_global_creation`, but by `myclass::myclass`. Instead, `cause_static_global_creation` assigns a value to the already-initialized object.

And as the class violates the Rule Of Three, it's no surprise that the assignment causes issues.

Comment: Update: Defining the copy constructors doesn't change this (see question edit). That's why I didn't include them in the minimal working example.

Comment: @JohnDoucette: The assignment operator in the first edit is wrong: `this->onTheHeap = other.onTheHeap;` is a shallow copy, so that pointer is still deleted twice.

Comment: @JohnDoucette: the signature is also wrong: it should be `myclass& operator=(const myclass& other)`

Comment: Okay, wow, that fixes things, but these are already properly defined in the library (double checked). Apparently my minimal working example no longer reproduces the behavior of interest. Going to have to think this through some more. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

`myclass` is constructed twice in your example.

First, with `len=0` by the statement `myclass existsForever;`.

Later, a temporary instance is constructed in `cause_static_global_creation` with `len=5` and it's assigned using the default assignment operator to `existsForever`. At this moment, `existsForever` and the temporary would share the same value of `onTheHeap` pointer. The temporary is destroyed immediately in `cause_static_global_creation`, freeing the memory for the vector. The same memory is freed again on the program end when the global instance is destroyed.

I have some suggestions how to fix that quickly.

1.Define the constructor as follows

```
myclass(int len=0)
{
  if ( len > 0 )
    onTheHeap = new vector<int>(len);
  else
    onTheHeap = NULL;
}
```

2.Use a smart pointer instead of a bare one.

```
std::shared_ptr<vector <int>> onTheHeap;
```

3.Don't construct the vector on the heap, use the instance member instead.

A longer way is to properly implement the assignment operator and the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think these comments/strategies cover your situation:

1. If you own class.h then just replace the `vector<int>*` with `vector`.  The compiler will take care of stack memory management and you will avoid heap leaks.
2. Note that global statics will consume the stack space for the duration of program execution, so byte-for-byte this is as "bad" as a dynamic memory leak.
3. Your double-delete is probably caused by a reference to the pointer escaping, as Benji noted via default copy ctor is likely.  You could replace this with a shared pointer (which doesn't need delete called) but stack is better.  Consider disabling copy constructor or writing a copy ctor that deep copies instead of shallow copies, and as Benji further noted if you disable assignment and copy construction and it doesn't compile you've found (one of) your problem(s).
4. Global statics should not be a problem in memory use unless they are a collection and keep expanding indefinitely without ever having their junk removed after use.  If the vector inside doesn't expand indefinitely without being cleaned up then these consume a constant amount of memory with respect to program execution.  Ensuring these have tighter lifespan would lead to better-factored code but would be considered premature optimization if your concern is memory.